# Several models in create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models:

- `User (first_name, last_name, mail)`
- `Article (name, info)`
- `Article_Author (user_id and article_id)`

In `Article_controller`, the `create` action looks like this:

```
def create
    @article = article.new(params[:article])

    @article_author = @article.article_authors.build(params[:article_authors])
    @article_authors.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, :flash=>{:notice=>'Article was successfully created.'} }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
end
```

Looks like it's okay, because in the `Article_Author` table I can see that `user_id` is equal to the current user id and the `article_id` is the current article id. In the view, when I write `<%= @article.article_authors %>`, it gives me the whole array of users: `[#<ArticleAuthors id: 1, user_id: 2, article_id: 10, created_at: "2013-01-15 18:46:39", updated_at: "2013-01-15 18:46:39">]`.

How can I just get the first name and last name?

Answer (score 0):

Then create a method in your model that fetches just the first and last name of the article authors:

```
# somewhere in models/article.rb
def article_authors_names
  article_authors.select('first_name, last_name')
end
```

You could rename to `authors_names` and simply call `@article.authors_names`.

Comment: @Poirot I have this exact code running on my machine. Perhaps you have not implemented properly?

Comment: I did as you wrote here, but it gives me empty hash.

Comment: @Poirot I am afraid it is something on your end. The code works fine here. I don't know what to suggest. You need to have a close look at your code and make sure it all fits together. Replace `first_name`, `last_name` with correct column names.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i wrote it in controller (not in model) and it worked. thank you very much

Comment: @Poirot great to hear you got it sorted.